# Do I need to define an array object when populating it with a ForEach in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
if (!$scope.aa.hasOwnProperty('x')) {
    $scope.aa.x = {}
    data.answers.forEach(function (element, index) {
        $scope.aa.x[index].c = null;
        $scope.aa.x[index].r = null;
        $scope.aa.x[index].text = element.text;
    });
}
```

But it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'c' of undefined
```

Do I need to define an array for `aa` and if so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. looks like `x` is an `array` and `x[index]` is an `object`:

```
        $scope.aa.x = [];
        data.answers.forEach(function (element, index) {
            $scope.aa.x[index] = {};
            $scope.aa.x[index].c = null;
            $scope.aa.x[index].r = null;
            $scope.aa.x[index].text = element.text;  
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, more idiomatic version of CD's answer is:

```
$scope.aa.x[index] = {
    c : null,
    r : null,
    text : element.text
}
```